# Only root of a sum?

Tags: summation, logarithms, roots

I have the following equation:
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\left(n_{i}-n\cdot p_{i}\right)\log p_{i}=0$

where $p_{1},p_{2},...,p_{k}$ are the unknown variables with the condition:
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}p_{i}=1\;\;\;\left(p_{i}\geq0\;\;\forall i=1,...,k\right)$

For the constants $n_{1},n_{2},...,n_{k}$ and $n$ the following condition holds:
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}n_{i}=n\;\;\;\left(n_{i}\geq0\;\;\forall i=1,...,k\right)$

It is easy to see, that $p_{i}=\large\frac{n_{i}}{n}$ $(i=1,...,k)$ is a solution for my equation.

Now my question:
Are there other solutions for $p_{1},p_{2}...,p_{k}$?

I am quite sure, that there are no other solutions, but i am not able to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are lots of other solutions. You have two equations in $k$ unknowns, so heuristically you expect a $(k-2)$-dimensional set of solutions. For example, when $k=3$, you expect a curve of solutions.

Here's a graph where I've taken $n_1=1$, $n_2=2$, and $n_3=3$. The horizontal axis is $p_1$ and the vertical axis is $p_2$ (while $p_3=1-p_1-p_2$ is not pictured). You can see there are lots of solutions, not just $(p_1,p_2) = (\frac16,\frac26)$ (the big dot).

[image: Lots of solutions]